# ASP.NET Session State and TempData

Tags: asp.net, session-state, tempdata

I've inherited a site which uses TempData to pass various model state objects back to contoller methods. i.e. a failed login will have the error message stored in the TempData object and read back out of memory when the index method gets called.

This all works fine if Session State is inproc, however I have implemeted a Session State database following this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx

The site now doesn't redirect to the index method like it used to and is instead throwing 500's. I've read up on this and it seems like TempData should work!

Any suggestions on how to dig into this to find the real issue or any pointers on getting this to work?

Comment: 1. Did you double check that the security context your web site is running under can access the database and its tables? 2. Check that you can persist and retrieve something simple like a string or integer using a quick test method/action in your controller. 3. If everything else works then it is probably an issue with the serialization / deserialization of the object you are writing/reading from the session state, check to make sure it is fully serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the objects are serializable. I've encountered a similar issue where inproc works and other session solutions don't, and it was down to the objects not being fully serializable.